# Is this a job for Yeoman?

Tags: json, code-generation, yeoman

I use Yeoman, and I dig it.

However recently I have been wanting more complex code generation tools - now I know I can build custom generators, but I am wondering if people think this is the role/job/whatever that Yeoman is built to play.

Examples are,

- Generating a base REST API (in Node) from a JSON schema
- Generating MySQL DB Schema from JSON schema etc.

Although I could bend Yeoman to do this - do people think this is a realistic direction?
Is there a better tool for the job?

(Currently I have a bunch of custom Node scripts that suffice).

Comment: I've had a similar idea a year later, did you find a solution? I don't think yeoman is restricted to frontend, [jhipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) is a popular backend project that is using yeoman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My humble opinion:
Yeoman is first and foremost a front end tool to create webapps.
Your task seems to be backend related.

You can still use grunt to scaffold your project though.
http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding

Cheers